Finding $x$ in ${98\choose30}+2{97\choose30}+3{96\choose30}\cdots+69{30\choose30}={100\choose x}$
I've been stuck on this question for some time, and really don't know where to start here.
I tried manipulating the expression to make it into a form easy to manipulate by using the Hockey-Stick Identity:
$${98\choose30}+2{97\choose30}+3{96\choose30}\cdots69{30\choose30}={100\choose x}$$
Reversing the LHS, we get:
$$69{30\choose30}+68{31\choose30}+67{32\choose30}\cdots{98\choose30}={100\choose x}$$
$$\implies{t_r}=(70-r){{29+r}\choose{30}}=70{{29+r}\choose{30}}-r{{29+r}\choose{30}}$$
$$\implies{S_r}=70({{30}\choose{30}}+{{31}\choose{30}}+{{32}\choose{30}}\cdots{{98}\choose{30}})-(1{{30}\choose{30}}+2{{31}\choose{30}}+3{{32}\choose{30}}\cdots69{{98}\choose{30}})$$
Using the Hockey-Stick Identity to simplify the first expression, we get:
$$\implies{S_r}=70{{99}\choose{31}}-(1{{30}\choose{30}}+2{{31}\choose{30}}+3{{32}\choose{30}}\cdots69{{98}\choose{30}})$$
I'm stuck on simplifying the second expression; could someone suggest a method I could use to continue from this step onwards, or an alternative better way to solve this problem?
Thankyou.

Please see this post. I used Approach0 to find it.

Hint: still use Hockey-Stick Identity. But please realize that $(69-r)\binom{30+r}{30}=100\binom{30+r}{r}-31\binom{31+r}{31}$.
